# Get balance solidity

Tags: solidity

I use hardhat to test a solidity contract but I get a different result with functions:

- getUserBalance (contract function)
- balanceOf

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract TestContract is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint;
   
    ...

    function getContractBalance() public view onlyOwner returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getUserBalance(address _owner) external view returns (uint) {
        return address(_owner).balance;
    }
}
```

test.js

```
...

beforeEach(async function () {
  Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestContract");
  [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();

  hardhatToken = await Token.deploy("test");
});

it("First test", async function () {
  let total = await hardhatToken.totalSupply() // BigNumber { value: "0" }
  let userBalance2 = await hardhatToken.getUserBalance(owner.address) // BigNumber { value: "9999979080649422213031" }
  let userBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address) // BigNumber { value: "0" }
  let cBalance = await hardhatToken.getContractBalance() // BigNumber { value: "0" }
})
```

I think it's because a different unity (ether -> wei) but I don't know why. Can you explain me ?

Thank you

Comment: where is the code of the balanceOf function?

Comment: I think it comes from the legacy of the ERC20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns the amount of eth of the `_owner`.

```
function getUserBalance(address _owner) external view returns (uint) {
    return address(_owner).balance;
}
```

This function returns the amount of the eth that the contract own.

```
function getContractBalance() public view onlyOwner returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
```

This function returns the amount of TOKEN that the owner has:

```
balanceOf(owner.address)
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the diff between getUserBalance(owner.address) and balanceOf(owner.address)

Comment: @Pad I updated the answer with the explanation of `balanceOf` function. The different is `getUserBalance` returns the amount of ETH, `balanceOf` returns the amount of the ERC20 token. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Ok, in other words: getUserBalance is for money (eth), balanceOf is for contract Item (erc20 token). Thats it ?